# Load Data using Spark by a single partition moves entire dataset under same location in S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm experiencing an issue in PySpark when creating a hive table and loading in the data to the table. So I'm using an Amazon s3 bucket as a data location and I'm creating a table as parquet and trying to load data into that table by a single partition, and I'm seeing some weird behavior. When selecting the data location in s3 of a parquet file to load into my table. All of the data is moved into the specified location in my create table command including the partitions I didn't specify in the load data command.Is this the intended behavior of loading the data in from a partioned parquet file? Is the previous file supposed to be moved/deleted from source directory?

```
    # create a data frame in pyspark with partitions
    df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 1, "x"), ("b", 2, "y"), ("c", 3, "y")], ["c1", "c2", "p"])
    
    # save it to S3
    df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("p").save("s3://bucket/data/")
```

In the current state S3 should have a new folder `data` with two folders which contain a parquet file in each partition.

> - s3://bucket/data/p=x/
>
>   - part-00001.snappy.parquet
> - s3://bucket/data/p=y/
>
>   - part-00002.snappy.parquet
>   - part-00003.snappy.parquet

```
    # create new table
    spark.sql("create table src (c1 string,c2 int) PARTITIONED BY (p string) STORED AS parquet LOCATION 's3://bucket/new/'")
    
    # load the saved table data from s3 specifying single partition value x
    spark.sql("LOAD DATA INPATH 's3://bucket/data/'INTO TABLE src PARTITION (p='x')")
    
    spark.sql("select * from src").show()
    
    # output: 
    # +---+---+---+
    # | c1| c2|  p|
    # +---+---+---+
    # +---+---+---+
```

After running the `load data` command, and looking at the table I'm left with no data loaded in. When checking S3 the data source we saved earlier is moved under `s3://bucket/new/` oddly enough it also brought over the other partitions along with it directory structure listed below.

> - s3://bucket/new/
>
>   - p=x/
>
>     - p=x/
>
>       - part-00001.snappy.parquet
>     - p=y/
>
>       - part-00002.snappy.parquet
>       - part-00003.snappy.parquet

Comment: Your file (s3://bucket/data/) may have partition columns included. if yes, you need to let hive  do dynamic partition and load. Use load sql without partition columns mentioned `spark.sql("LOAD DATA INPATH 's3://bucket/data/'INTO TABLE src PARTITION (p)") `

Comment: Without specifying the value of the partition. I get a parse exception:

```
Found an empty partition key 'p'.
== SQL ==
LOAD DATA INPATH 's3://bucket/data/' INTO TABLE src PARTITION (p)
--------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```